# Maximum of two real numbers (scalars) on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like a for loop to run whilst 'a' is the larger of 1 and 'b'. How do I make this happen? I guessed that 'for a = max(1,b)' would do it, but I ended up with a problem down the line that I think was caused by this.

Comment: Is that maybe what you want: `while a > 1 & a > b`? I have a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: You'd want `>=` there, not `>`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `while a==max(1,b)`. The `for` statement you have will run a single time, with a set to the maximum of 1 and b's value at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
while (a > max(1,b))
end
```